# Visual Studio - better indication of build status

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, build-process

When I do builds in Visual studio, it would be great to have a better indicator that the build is done.

Sometimes I navigate away from VS while it is building and I have to switch between VS and another window to find out if VS finished building.

Are there ways to make the "build is done" status more obvious?  Play a sound or something else?

Comment: I would really like an answer to this as well!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Growl for windows](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/) to hook up to Visual Studio.

Set it up with the visual studio plugin (found [here](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/apps.aspx)), and you will have very clear indication of build success/failure.

Notifications show up like this:

[image]

Comment: I like the visual indicator because I might not always have my headphones on.  Thank you!

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot to Oded and the Growl developers. I have been looking for something like this for a long time, since I often end up starting a compile of our huge visual studio solution and forget about  it in the meantime... (it takes up to 50 minutes to compile)

Answer (score 7):

If you use the Sounds control panel applet, you'll find that there is a section for Visual Studio. "Build Success" is one of the sounds.

I prefer "Windows Print Complete", which gives a nice "cheery" sound. I use "Windows Hardware Fail" for build failure. It really sounds like something is badly wrong.

Comment: I like the visual indicator because I might not always have my headphones on.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, I'd been searching for something like this! I would have never looked there.

FYI: I had to restart VS2010 for this to take effect.